# rebol utf-8 library : map has no value

Tags: rebol

I downloaded http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=utf-8.r 
when executing it, I get this error:

"map has no value".

I can't find rebol map libary anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `utf-8.r` script has a dependency declared in his header:

```
    Needs: [%hof.r]
```

You can find that script [here](http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=hof.r). It contains the `map` function definition among many others.